# The error massage show "The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. " How can i convert the parameter into a String?

Tags: string, dart, dart-pub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnER0.png)//I had declared the image URL in the other dart file as String so that each image can be displayed to the related articles. But the parameter can accept String as the items. How can I convert the items i as string?

Answer (score 0):

```
child:Image.asset(i)
```

replace with

```
child:i
```